# ArrayList of Shapes

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, graphics2d

I have some problem with my code. I want to write program which paints Rectangle, Circle and one more shape created from points. I want to use Graphics2D and here is my question: How to make one ArrayList of all this shapes? Is it even possible? I made sth like this:

```
List<Shape> shapesArray = new ArrayList<Shape>();
shapesArray.add(new Rectangle2D.Double());
shapesArray.get(0).setFrameFromDiagonal(point_a, point_b)
```

When i do it like that i can't use Rectangle2D methods.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for sure do this:

```
List<Shape> shapesArray = new ArrayList<Shape>();
shapesArray.add(new Rectangle2D.Double());
shapesArray.get(0).setFrameFromDiagonal(point_a, point_b)
```

but to call specific class methods a cast is required...
to be sure if a shape in the list can be cast you need to check the instance

like:

```
if(shapesArray.get(0) instanceof Rectangle2D){
      ((Rectangle2D)shapesArray.get(0)).setFrameFromDiagonal(point_a, point_b)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats what i wanted to do. Works perfect now :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. The only thing you are missing is a check and a cast to the original object before you can use it. Here's some code:

```
if(shapesArray.get(0) instanceof Rectangle2D)
 Rectangle2D rectangle = (Rectangle2D) shapesArray.get(0);
// Use methods and do other checks
```